# If $\dim(A+B)=\dim(A\cap B)+1$, then $A \subset B$ or $B \subset A$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A,B$ be linear subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$. Show that if
$$
\dim(A+B) = \dim(A \cap B) + 1, \tag{1}
$$
then one of the space is a subset of the other,
$$
A \subset B \text{ or } B \subset A. \tag{2}
$$

By the dimension theorem, then (1)
$$
\dim(A+B)=\dim(A)+\dim(B)-\dim(A \cap B) = \dim(A \cap B) + 1, \tag{3}
$$
so that
$$
\dim(A)+\dim(B)= 2\dim(A \cap B) + 1. \tag{4}
$$

I can't see where to go next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $A \cap B \subseteq A \subseteq A+B$, it follows that
$$
 \dim A \cap B \leq \dim A \leq \dim(A+B) = \dim(A \cap B) + 1.
$$
Hence, either $\dim A = \dim(A \cap B)$ or $\dim A = \dim(A+B)$. What follows from each of these two cases?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** To prove the contraposative, suppose neither $A \subset B$ or $B\subset A$. Then $A\cap B$ is strictly contained in both $A$ and $B$, so $\dim(A\cap B) < \dim(A), \dim(B)$.

Comment: @CameronBuie Sorry, I don't see how that's relevant, could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: Oops! As I was writing out my explanation, I saw that it wasn't necessary to note that, at all. Your hint is really all that is needed. (+1)

Comment: @CameronBuie No worries,thanks anyway! When I wrote the hint I couldn't find a way to indicate the direction I was thinking in without giving the answer away entirely. Since I like to leave more of a solution hidden rather than less, I left it as it was, although I appreciate that it's not immediately clear where the argument's going!